# Black screen on background of transparent activity in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I am working on a plugin that requires to move to a new Android Activity (native Activity or FragmentActivity) from the main activity (that is extended from UnityPlayerActivity). The new activity has a transparent background so that the scene of the Unity game can be seen at the background, but when the new activity opens the background goes black instead of being transparent.

Answer (score 1):

it can be done easily as you says that you use a fragments so you can add this activity in a Viewflipper and add them as a view so when its flipping on the main activity its got the same background of main activity